# Read double fields from structure

Tags: c#, struct

I´m not very experienced with C# but I urgently have to read a variable from a structure given in a library.

this is the definition of the structure in the library:

```
public struct mtLocation {
    public bool bAltitudeValid;
    public bool bCoordinatesValid;
    public double dAltitude;
    public ulong dateTime;
    public double dLatitude;
    public double dLongitude; }
```

I want to use write the value of dLatitude and dLongitute into my own double variables in order to use them in my program.

Answer (score 6):

```
mtLocation myLocation = new mtLocation();

...

double latitude = myLocation.dLatitude;
double longitude = myLocation.dLongitude;
```

Comment: `long` is a reserved keyword... but I assume you already know that ;)

Comment: You can use reserved keywords as identifiers if you prefix them with @ such as in "long @long = long.MaxValue". I never had to use this feature and I'm not sure I would really want to.